# How to make Bootstrap's .container fill full available width and height irrespective of its contents' size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

As the title says, I'm trying to make a `div.container` full (available) width and height, not more, not less. I've been playing around with the following code and I haven't figured out how to do it, despite several searches and attempts. My CSS knowledge is very rusty.

This is what I have now (https://jsfiddle.net/qf1azopr/1/), which looks close to what I'm trying to do (only because of the `padding: 255px 0px;`). However, it only does on my screen, and I know this is not the proper way to do it.

With this, if I shrink the window, then the content automatically overflows it and the footer is out of sight. I'm not so worried about this, but I know there will be some space below the footer on bigger screens. If you see [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), the footer is always at the bottom, even if you shrink the window. The content only overflows it when it shrinks to some specific size. This is what I'd like to accomplish.

I think the actual way to do it with with the padding, but I'm not sure how. I'd just like the content, from navbar to footer, to just fit the available space and only overflow it if the window gets too small. What should change with the window size is the padding of `the div.front`.

How can I do this?

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.front {
  padding: 255px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 90px;
}

.lorem {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Name</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarScroll" aria-controls="navbarScroll" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarScroll">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto my-2 my-lg-0 navbar-nav-scroll" style="--bs-scroll-height: 100px;">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    Tools
                  </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Tool 1</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container full-size">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="front">
      <h1>Some Title</h1>
      <p class="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer class="py-3">
  <ul class="nav justify-content-center border-bottom pb-3 mb-3">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">About</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">Privacy Policy</a></li>
  </ul>
  <p class="text-center text-muted">© 2022 Company, Inc</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Use 100vh on the container.

Comment: @NehaSoni That actually makes the content overflow. Note that there's also a navbar and a footer.

Comment: So, basically, you want the navbar and footer to be fixed and the content to be scrolled in the middle of both?

Comment: @NehaSoni Well. I want the navbar and footer to be fixed, but the content to be of variable height depending those. The content should overflow only if the window gets too small.